# Multivariable Chain Rule given Contour Map

Tags: multivariable-calculus

[image]

I am struggling with Part C. We know that:

$$\frac{dh}{dt} = \frac{dh}{dx}\cdot\frac{dx}{dt} + \frac{dh}{dy}\cdot\frac{dy}{dt}$$

We also know that:

$$\frac{dx}{dt} = \cos(t) = 1$$
$$\frac{dy}{dt} = 2t + 3 = 3$$

Making our original equation:

$$\frac{dh}{dt} = \frac{dh}{dx} + 3\frac{dh}{dy}$$

I do not know how to proceed from here. Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gradient vector $\nabla f = (\partial f/\partial x,\partial f/\partial y)$ is approximately $(1,-2)$, since the function changes by about those amounts when you make a unit increase in $x$ or $y$ respectively, at the point $(x,y)=(0,2)$, while the velocity vector you are looking at is $(dx/dt,dy/dt)=(1,3)$, so the dot product of these is about $1-6=-5$.

Comment: You could do better, if you try to get a better gradient approximation, by looking at the average between (1) the approximation by increasing each variable by one and (2) by decreasing instead.

Comment: Makes perfect sense. Thanks!